# Problems in creating a static site with WordPress

Tags: pages, menus, static-website

I want to create a static, company brochure site.  I created a page called "HOME" and I was able to change the reading settings to static, and select "HOME" from the drop down box.  I then created a page named "ABOUT-US".  It appears in the main menu, but when I click on it I get a 404 error.  I also need to create an page called "ADVANTAGES", with sub pages (e.g. Advantage-A, Advantage-B, etc.).  How can I do this?

I am new to WP. I've tried blogging and its fine.  Can anyone suggest a tutorial or book for this?  It would be a great help.  I Googled it in vain, it was no big help.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your permalink settings: `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`

Second, check to ensure you don't somehow have a Page slug conflict. Go to `Dashboard -> Pages`, click the "Trash" tab, and ensure you don't have any Pages in the trash (if so, delete them if you don't need them).

Third, check the page-slug for your "About-Us" Page, and ensure that it matches what is being linked in your Page Menu. If they don't match, that will explain your 404 error.

Comment: 1.Permalink : I have created .htaccess in the main directory but when i try to create a new custom structure :/advantages,i get "You should update your .htaccess now."

Comment: 2.I dont have any file in trash.

Comment: 3.I don't have any slug named "About-us".,i have link named advantages. . .

Comment: @kracekumar 1. Sounds like your .htaccess file is not writable by your webserver. You'll want to update the permissions on the file so the webserver can write to it and then retry setting your permlink structure.

Comment: @Manzabar:.htaccess file has permission 755

Comment: You should NEVER have to add your own rewrite rules. WordPress adds them itself. If WordPress is unable to add its own mod_rewrite rules, after visiting `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` (and saving settings, for good measure), then the problem is write-access to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: *"I don't have any slug named "About-us".,i have link named advantages."* In your original question, you said that you created a Page called "about-us": *Now I created a page named 'about-us',it appears in the main menu ,when I click on I get error 404*. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Chip Bennet :I solved the .htaccess problem by using 'chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress/',Now permalink works fine. . .

Comment: @Chip Bennet:I first created a page and deleted it and again I re created. . . .Now I have the following problems 1.404 Not found

Comment: When you deleted the Page, did you empty it from the Trash before re-creating it? If not, empty the trash, and then check the Page slug of the newly created Page. Make sure it doesn't have a "-2" appended (e.g. `about-us-2` instead of `about-us`).

Comment: @Chip Bennet: No -2 is not appended,I emptied the trash

Comment: Where/how do you get this 404 error?

Comment: `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=15&action=edit'when i click on view page, i get 404 error,Permalink: http://localhost/wordpress/c

Comment: That URL you pasted is for a **Post**, rather than for a **Page**. Check your permalink settings again.

Comment: @chip :What exactly,here is my .htaccess   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Comment: Is WordPress installed in a sub-directory? If so, make sure your site URL settings are correct. Also, WordPress automatically writes your `mod_rewrite` rules. Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` and click "Save Settings" to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: wordpress is installed in /var/www/wordpress,In `Permalinks` Category base  
Tag base ,
Category permalink, structure tag,Tag permalink, structure tag ,Page permalink,structure tag,
Author permalink'were optional and empty and clicked  `save changes`,in custom i entered /c and i got `Permalink structure updated.`.Then `http://localhost/wordpress/c`,yields 404 :(

Comment: Try `Dashboard -> Settings -> General`, and verify that **WordPress address (URL)** and **Site address (URL)** are correct.

Comment: `site url:http://localhost/wordpress`   `site URL:http://localhost/wordpress` both are correct,wordpress is installed in `/var/www/wordpress`so i think both are correct

Comment: `wordpress url :http://localhost/wordpress`